# error while generating apk in android studio after gradle build is successfull

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, apk

while generating apk getting this error i have already tried upadting the pugins also as it was recommended

```
Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  
The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
  - icepick-processor-3.2.0.jar (frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0)
  - auto-service-1.0-rc2.jar (com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2)
Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.
```

Comment: yea.. follow the link what it says?

Comment: That page is not loading getting error 404

Comment: it is loading fine for me..Here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies?utm_source=android-studio#annotation_processor  See the answer and modify the code as per. it is the solution what documentation says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly add annotation processors in gradle. Putting the following in your gradle dependencies should fix it:

```
annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2'
```